# yum update gives 'Obsoleted by ...' error

Tags: mysql, yum

My OS is `CentOS 6.9`, and I'm trying to upgrade mysql 5.5 to 5.7 with this link: https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/213403429-How-to-upgrade-MySQL-5-5-to-5-6-5-7-or-MariaDB-5-5-to-10-0-10-1-10-2-on-Linux

But `# yum update mysql` gives me errors :

```
Error: Package: php-mysql-5.4.45-14.el6.remi.x86_64 (@remi)
           Requires: libmysqlclient.so.18()(64bit)
           Removing: mysql-libs-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (@remi)
               libmysqlclient.so.18()(64bit)
           Obsoleted By: mysql-community-libs-5.7.21-1.el6.x86_64 (mysql57-community)
               Not found
Error: Package: php-mysql-5.4.45-14.el6.remi.x86_64 (@remi)
           Requires: libmysqlclient.so.18(libmysqlclient_18)(64bit)
           Removing: mysql-libs-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (@remi)
               libmysqlclient.so.18(libmysqlclient_18)(64bit)
           Obsoleted By: mysql-community-libs-5.7.21-1.el6.x86_64 (mysql57-community)
               Not found
Error: Package: php-mysql-5.4.45-14.el6.remi.x86_64 (@remi)
           Requires: libmysqlclient.so.18(libmysqlclient_16)(64bit)
           Removing: mysql-libs-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (@remi)
               libmysqlclient.so.18(libmysqlclient_16)(64bit)
           Obsoleted By: mysql-community-libs-5.7.21-1.el6.x86_64 (mysql57-community)
               Not found
```

I tried `yum clean metadata` and `yum clean all` several times but it's not working.
Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend to switch from **php-mysql** (which use libmysqlclient) to **php-mysqlnd** which provides the same set of extensionx using the PHP native driver.

```
yum shell
> remove php-mysql
> install php-mysqlnd
> run
```

This will drop the dependency, so will resolve your issue.

BTW, please remind that PHP 5.4.45 have reach its end of life, so I also heartily recommend you update to a maintained version (5.6+)

P.S. All RPM of any PHP version >= 5.5 only provides the php-mysqlnd package.